# Issues with zsh permissions on my mac m1

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

I am trying to install kubectl on my macOS using this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/)

But in the final step when I go on to check 'kubectl version --client
', I get the error **zsh: permission denied: kubectl**

I cannot understand the reason for it as I gave appropriate permissions to kubectl already. Please help.

[image: mac]

Comment: It’s owned by “root”.  See the `chown` command? Try running with `sudo`

Comment: sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/kubectl

Comment: Please don't post text as an image; see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: @LincD. , I tried the command, I get the error "chmod: –: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Allan, but the chown command is already run with sudo.

Comment: `chown` changes *ownership* of a file and must be run as root.  When you execute the file, you’re executing the file as your logged in user.  Now, I’m betting that the app needs to be run as root to work, so preface the command with `sudo`

Comment: Your image shows an existing file with that pathname. If necessary, correct the path and try again. 'kubectl' seems to be executable only by root.